# Accessing SQL Server system views with EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I want to get data from SQL Server system views using EF Core 7.
Particularly, `sys.database_firewall_rules`. I want to show the user existing firewall rules and make it possible to add/remove firewall rules.

For inserting/deleting I have used the `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync()` method and it is working ok.

I know EF Core 8 is supporting unmapped type queries, but I am working on a large codebase that I can't migrate to EF Core 8.

Is it possible to create a class for firewall rules, add dbset to datacontext and somehow make it readonly and point it to `sys.database_firewall_rules`?

Comment: Yes, you can just add a class and DbSet with .HasNoKey()